# How to list the assigned/leased IP adresses by DHCP server in Rapberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, dhcp, dnsmasq

I am using a raspberry pi -3 and installed dnsmasq and dhcpd server for auto IP assignment.
how to know the devices connected and their IPs.

Answer (score 2):

In Pi we have the path of lease file is
`/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`

In Ubuntu it is
`/var/lib/NetworkManager/*.lease`
in some cases (specially with dhcpd) it is
`/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`

For pi we can display the IP address of named device by
`cat /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases | grep "ClienDevName"|cut -d " " -f 3| awk '{print $1}`'

in this command `-d` is for "delimiter" which is space by `" "` and `-f 3` is to print the 3rd value after cutting with  delimiter space i.e `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

DNSMASQ leases file is located at /var/lib/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.leases

DHCPD leases file is located at /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases